# DeleteFile() or File.Delete() or Kill()

Tags: vb.net

I'm migrating some code from VBA to VB.net and i have stuck at one simple thing. How to delete file.
Can some one explain what is difference between these three methods:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("D:\file.xls")

System.IO.File.Delete("D:\file.xls")

FileSystem.Kill("D:\file.xls")
```

I only need to delete all specific file types in the folder. With VBA I used FileSystem.Kill, and with this method I don't have to loop through all files, I can delete all the specific files using

```
 FileSystem.Kill("D:\*.xls*")
```

What is best practice in VB.net to delete specific files?

Comment: It makes no difference, they all do the same thing.  The My namespace was added in vb.net to help programmers conquer the giant .NET framework, it makes often-used functions easier to find.  Kill() provides compatibility with code that was written in older Basic versions, like VBA.  File.Delete() is the one that is available in any language, tends to be the right choice.  But it is your choice.

Comment: `explain what is difference between these three methods` did you research these methods?

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the answer. I was hoping for an answer like that.

Answer (score 2):

The first option and the second are effectively the same, as the `My` namespace just aliases types elsewhere (in this case, `System.IO.File`).

With that in mind, I prefer the second option, as it is more portable across environments (I've been several places that mix the use of VB.Net with other .Net languages like C# or F#, which don't have the `My` namespace).

I avoid use of the vb6-era APIs, but really there's nothing wrong with it for the moment. Still, given the same mixed-environment issues as before, I would tend to write code like this:

```
Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("D:\");
For Each file As FileInfo In dir.EnumerateFiles("*.xls")
    file.Delete()
Next
```

Or this:

```
For Each fileName As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles("D:\", "*.xls")
    File.Delete(fileName)
Next
```

Comment: Also there is a notice in the [`Kill` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.kill?view=netframework-4.8), *"The `My` feature gives you better productivity and performance in file I/O operations than `Kill`."*.

Comment: Also, why was it named `VB.Net`, and not `VB#`?